# How to hide style section in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

How to hide the right bottom section (style section) of dev tools?

Comment: You can resize it. Maybe there's a way to hide it by writing a custom devtools theme, but I'm not sure it'll work because devtools uses shadow DOM.

Answer (score 28):

By default, this is the way it is placed [image: Default]

But from the settings -> preferences -> Panel layout -> "Horizontal" [image: Panel Layout]

With this option, we can bring the style pane to the bottom [image: to bottom]

Comment: Thank you! Its a shame that auto is ON by default and doing its semi-random resizing. Also a shotout to chrome-devs it is actually NOT that easy to find this out inside the preferences..

Comment: 2023; does not work anymore.

Comment: as of May 2023 it is working now, Version 113.0.5672.93

Answer (score 13):

There's no way to hide it. You can resize it so that it's pushed off to the side, as [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) mentioned.

[image]

Here's a different UI setup that you may prefer:

If you [undock your DevTools window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#placement) and make it narrow, the Styles pane moves below the DOM Tree. From there, you can minimize it.

[image]

You can also achieve this UI setup just by making your DevTools window more narrow. You don't *have* to undock it.

Comment: Thanks, Kayce. I was expecting if there is any way to hide because while using js console and Elements tabs, I really don't find the usefulness of styles drawer.

Comment: There's also an entire tab dedicated to the Console. Click **Console** (next to **Elements** in the screenshot in my answer) to open it. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, that right but I had to use both console and elements tab for some DOM manipulation.

Comment: Link rot.   You linked to something to explain how it solves a problem, without ever saying what that thing is, and now that link doesn't explain anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can collapse the sidebar more when you selected computed rather than styles. Styles has too large of a minimum width and the computed tab collapses to the size of the chevron icon.

Computed tab collapsed:
[image: Computed tab collapsed screenshot]

Selection of computed tab:
[image: selection of computed tab screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

since the chatbots haven't figured this one out, here's how to get rid of the annoying Styles pane for chromium:

- Ctrl+Shift+I (Windows/Linux) or Cmd+Option+I (Mac) to open dev tools.
- Click the settings icon
- Under "Panel layout" select horizontal

the extra pane will now be at the bottom, height-adjustable.